# Heroku SSL: install intermediate cert?

Tags: ssl, heroku, https

My registrar, gandi, gave me an intermediate cert to install, so I have 3 files:

1. Private key file (server.key)
2. Certificate file (mycert.crt)
3. Intermediate cert (GandiSomething.pem)

I'm using the [SSL Beta](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-beta) service on heroku. The heroku CLI `heroku _certs:add`, takes exactly two arguments, CRT and KEY. how do I install the intermediate cert?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Paul is right, you can combine certificates:

```
cat ssl.crt middle.crt root.crt > all.crt
```

*Be assured that newlines at the end of cert files!*

And upload it to **Heroku** (use `add` if you haven't **SSL Endpoint** yet):

```
heroku certs:update --app $YOUR_APP --confirm $YOUR_APP all.crt private.key
```

But there are some tricks you haven't forget:

1. Update your **DNS CNAME** record. Change target from `<app>.herokuapp.com` to secure `<domain>.herokudns.com` (be careful, if you have `*.your.domain` record it can catch requests and forward it to another server)
2. Check the **cert chain** works right: [SSL Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html)
3. **Flush** local DNS: [Flush DNS tips](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How%20To%20Clear%20Your%20DNS%20Cache) (antivirus also can patch and cache you connections)
4. **Restart** your browser (to flush browser's cache too)
5. Check your app with browser by **https://** connection

Answer (score 7):

The solution here is to combine the intermediate cert and the generated cert into one file, as described [here](https://success.trendmicro.com/solution/1106466). Because that link is shady, here's how the cert file should look once combined:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEKjCCAxKgAwIBAgIEOGPe+DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBtDEUMBIGA1UEChML
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
wfsm5p9GJKaxB825DOgNghYAHZaS/KYIoA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Then, this command will work:

`heroku _certs:add --app name-of-my-app file-with-combined-certs.crt myserver.key`

Comment: Mine is looking like this.. Following the accepted-answer-post, and doing cat on my certificates.. should it be a problem that there's no line-break between the certificates?

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFajCCBFKgAwIBAgIQYIe2ygXshm+UppXSPTQtCDANBgkqhkiG9w0BA-----END CERTIFICATE----------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIETTAwIBAgIDAjpxMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEIxCzAJBg
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it in as an argument. Put the intermediate in the middle, it takes it as another argument. Then check heroku certs and report back if it doesn't work.

Comment: this doesn't work, the command gives: ▸    Usage: heroku _certs:add CRT KEY
 ▸    You gave this command too many arguments. Try the command again without these extra arguments.

Comment: What you need to do is to combine the intermediate certificate like [here](http://esupport.trendmicro.com/solution/en-US/1106466.aspx). Include it as the first certificate argument.

Comment: Wow, this was from a long time ago. Glad I could help.